# Modeling web traffic distribution

Tags: distributions, fat-tails, heavy-tailed

I have to test some functionalities of a software. I need to simulate the web traffic to a server in terms of the numbers of access. What it is the most suitable function distribution for this task?

Comment: What do requests to your server actually look like? One somewhat easy thing to do is to just record a bunch of traffic and then replay it for a test. It often takes a lot of work to make simulated traffic that even sort-of resembles real traffic.

Comment: Are simple gets to medias. I can't use actual data.

Comment: I assume "medias" means files of some sort. Can you not use real data for privacy reasons or because you have no way of getting it? If you really can't even _look_ at past real data, then you're pretty much screwed, because you won't even have something to fit a statistical model to. Something to keep in mind no matter what you do: The distribution of file sizes and of # of accesses will be very lop-sided (may look sort of like a log-normal or power-law), so make sure that your traffic-generator has _at least_ those properties (it will certainly be different from real traffic in other ways).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your workload characterization as well as the system.

Take a loot at [Long-lasting transient conditions in simulations with heavy-tailed workloads](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=268733) by Crovella and Lipsky publish at Winter Simulation Conference 1997. Specifically, read the paper, use its references, and also check who reference this paper.

A quick and dirty response would be modeling the interarrival request times as an Exponential distribution. But you should consider your system as well, which implies increase or decrease the number of workload generators (clients) in order to make them produce significant requests capable of impact on the system. You also can check [Bench4Q: A QoS-Oriented E-Commerce Benchmark](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=6032323) as a reference of how architect your testbed.

As more details of your problem you point, more accurate responses will appear. (my opinion)

Answer (score 1):

[Wiki Site Traffic_generation_model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_generation_model) is a starter. It describes two models,

- the more complicated 3GPP2 model, and
- the easier [802.16 model](http://ieee802.org/16/tg3/contrib/802163c-01_30r1.pdf)

The latter is a combination of three processes:

> - Interrupted Poisson Process (IPP)
> - Interrupted Discreet Process (IDP)
> - Interrupted Renewal Process (IRP)

They are run in parallel to generate traffic. The main point for you is the IPP, which is used to simulate HTTP and FTP traffic. Short summary:

4 processes, each with different parameters. Each process has two states

- ON state, where it sends traffic
- OFF state, where it is idle

There is a switch probability given by a poisson distribution. You can model this by getting the time to the next switch from an exponential distribution.

In the ON state, messages are sent (one-directionally)